# Alternatives to ApacheBench for profiling my code speed

Tags: python, profiling, benchmarking, latency, apachebench

I've done some experiments using Apache Bench to profile my code response times, and it doesn't quite generate the right kind of data for me. I hope the good people here have ideas.

Specifically, I need a tool that

- Does HTTP requests over the network (it doesn't need to do anything very fancy)
- Records response times as accurately as possible (at least to a few milliseconds)
- Writes the response time data to a file without further processing (or provides it to my code, if a library)

I know about `ab -e`, which prints data to a file. The problem is that this prints only the quantile data, which is useful, but not what I need. The `ab -g` option would work, except that it doesn't print sub-second data, meaning I don't have the resolution I need.

I wrote a few lines of Python to do it, but the httplib is horribly inefficient and so the results were useless. In general, I need better precision than pure Python is likely to provide. If anyone has suggestions for a library usable from Python, I'm all ears.

I need something that is high performance, repeatable, and reliable.

I know that half my responses are going to be along the lines of "internet latency makes that kind of detailed measurements meaningless." In my particular use case, this is not true. I need high resolution timing details. Something that actually used my HPET hardware would be awesome.

Throwing a bounty on here because of the low number of answers and views.

Comment: I ended up building a custom tool to take my measurements using a combination of Python and libcurl. libcurl provides good resolution timing measurements for each part of the http request/response process, allowing me to get the precise measurements I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in two ways.

With "loadrunner" which is a wonderful but pretty expensive product (from I think HP these days).

With combination perl/php and the Curl package. I found the CURL api slightly easier to use from php. Its pretty easy to roll your own GET and PUT requests. I would also recommend manually running through some sample requests with Firefox and the LiveHttpHeaders add on to captute the exact format of the http requests you need.

Comment: Loadrunner sounds like a great piece of software. Definitely out of my budget (and overkill - I'm really mainly doing statistics here). I actually only need to do HEAD requests, but the idea of using curl as a library seems like a good one.

Comment: Do you know if curl can be convinced to do timing for keep-alive sessions?

Comment: Just a followup here - Curl (libcurl in Python, actually) provided a great wealth of information directly related to the points I wanted to investigate. I guess building my own tools for my own problem really is the right answer sometimes. As a bonus, libcurl is a lot more efficient than any network code I might write myself.

Answer (score 1):

[JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/get-started.html) is pretty handy. It has a GUI from which you can set up your requests and threadpools and it also can be run from the command line.

Comment: That does look like a handy tool. A bit overkill for what I need here, but I'll keep it in mind for other projects. How precise is it? My concern with bigger tools like that is that the GUI and all the "other stuff" may add noise to my results (Granted, I'm looking for results more precise than most web benchmarking tools are designed to provide).

Comment: Regarding the preciseness - do one test run with ApacheBench (or whatever you trust) and another with JMeter. If your server is consistent performance-wise, you should get close results from both runs. This way you can ensure if there is any GUI overhead.

Comment: @mindas I need far greater precision than a test like that will reveal.

Comment: Well, in that case you might want to edit your question and explain why and what precision you need (and why you trust ApacheBench - if you do).

Answer (score 1):

If you can code in Java, you can look at the combination of [JUnitPerf + HttpUnit](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#junitperf-support).

The downside is that you will have to do more things yourself. But at the price of this you will get unlimited flexibility and arguably more preciseness than with GUI tools, not to mention HTML parsing, JavaScript execution, etc.

There's also another project called [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) which seems to be purposed for a similar task but I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: Yeah... but I don't need HTML parsing, javascript, etc. I just need the time that it takes for a request to leave my machine and for me to get the start of a HEAD request back. JUnitPerf is probably a bit higher level than I need, but I will take a look at it.

Comment: I took a look at The Grinder. It seems to be closer to what I'm looking for, but still has some inefficiencies that worry me. For example, "HTTPClient sends a POST as two PDUs ... This is a consequence of the conservative implementation of HTTP/1.1 pipelining in HTTPClient."

Answer (score 1):

A good reference of opensource perfomance testing tools: http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php

You will find descriptions and a "most popular" list

Answer (score 1):

[httperf](http://code.google.com/p/httperf/) is very powerful.

Comment: He included the essential part - the name of the tool.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a script to drive 10 boxes on the same switch to generate load by "replaying" requests to 1 server.  I had my web app logging response time (server only) to the granularity I needed, but I didn't care about the response time to the client.  I'm not sure you care to include the trip to and from the client in your calculations, but if you did it shouldn't be to difficult to code up. I then processed my log with a script which extracted the times per url and did scatter plot graphs, and trend graphs based on load.

This satisfied my requirements which were:

- Real world distribution of calls to different urls.
- Trending performance based on load.
- Not influencing the web app by running other intensive ops on the same box.

I did controller as a shell script that foreach server started a process in the background to loop over all the urls in a file calling curl on each one.  I wrote the log processor in Perl since I was doing more Perl at that time.